# Problems with text-align : center

Tags: html, css

**This is my CSS.**

```css
<style type="text/css"> .chart-legend {
  text-align: center;
}
.chart-legend li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.chart-legend li span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-6" class="thumbnail">
  <div class="thumbnail" style="width:100%">
    <h4>  <span class="label label-primary">{{ a.title }}</span></h4>
    <div>
      <canvas id="canvas{{loopIndex}}" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here, the first legend entry gets aligned to the center, whereas the second entry does not go right below the aligned first one, but leaving some space towards the right. Below, is the image. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: can you post the generated html or a screenshot of inspect element just for the part <div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend">

Comment: If you create an exact demo of the issue, you can receive help faster.

Comment: Elements are centered perfectly. What do you need?

Comment: Do text-align:left and add padding, they will then align nicely to whichever osition you chose them to be. As others have said, they are now centered,  having different lenghts makes it look like that.
Another possibility would be you can have the squares align left and the text align center, i think that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all :) But this kinda worked well for me! :)

```
.chart-legend {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

They both look centred to me. They are individually centred, and as they are different lengths, they will not have their left edges aligned with each other.

I suspect you want to let them left align inside a div, and then centre the div.

Also, unless I'm missing something, you haven't included all the HTML necessary to generate your attached image.

Answer (score 1):

They are centered,Because of different length its look like this..

If you want something like this.You should set a `padding:somthing` according to your need 
and if its and for html element you can set `left` property as well. 

Hope this will help you..